# Using Square Connect PHP SDK, UpsertCatalogObject fatal error

Tags: square-connect

I am using the square connect php sdk, and I am getting the following error, and haven't been able to find any solution. I am trying to push a few new categories that have been added on my app (within mysql database).

**Building the catelogObject**

```
foreach ($push_array as $key => $cat_name) {
    $category = $this->products_lib->get_category($cat_name);
    $idempotency_key = uniqid('',true);
    $push_obj = new stdClass();
    $push_obj->type = 'CATEGORY';
    $push_obj->id = '#' . trim($category->name);
    $push_obj->category_data = ['name'=>trim($category->name)];
    $push_obj->present_at_all_locations = true;
    $catelogObject = ["idempotency_key" => $idempotency_key, 'object' => $push_obj];
    print_r($catelogObject);
    $response = $square_connect->upsert_category($catelogObject);
}
```

**Produces**

```
(
    [idempotency_key] => 5996186208eae4.27853833
    [object] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => CATEGORY
            [id] => #Drinks
            [category_data] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Drinks
                )
            [present_at_all_locations] => 1
        )
)
```

**square_connect class**

```
class SquareConnect {
    private $access_token = "***********************";
    private $sandbox_access_token = "sandbox-*********************";
    public function get_locations() {
        SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($this->access_token);
        $locations_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationsApi();
        echo $locations_api->listLocations();
    }
    public function get_categories() {
        SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($this->access_token);
        $api = new \SquareConnect\Api\CatalogApi();
        $retobj = json_decode($api->listCatalog(null, 'CATEGORY'));
        // $categories = $retobj->objects;
        return $retobj->objects;
    }
    public function upsert_category($category_object) {
        SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($this->access_token);
        $api = new \SquareConnect\Api\CatalogApi();
        // return $apiResponse = json_decode($api->UpsertCatalogObject($category_object));
        print_r(json_decode($api->UpsertCatalogObject($category_object))) ;
    }
    public function get_items() {
        SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($this->access_token);
        $api = new \SquareConnect\Api\CatalogApi();
        echo $api->listCatalog(null, 'ITEM');
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error :

**Fatal error**: Access to undeclared static property: stdClass::$swaggerTypes in /vendor/square/connect/lib/ObjectSerializer.php on line 43

Hope that is clear enough, and thanks in advance for assistance

**Edit**

```
[DEBUG] HTTP Request body  ~BEGIN~

~END~
[DEBUG] HTTP Response body ~BEGIN~
{"objects":[{"type":"CATEGORY","id":"52IJHDSD67VAQNJ3GQB5TVRX","updated_at":"2017-08-16T19:50:58.373Z","version":1502913058373,"is_deleted":false,"custom_attributes":[{"name":"straight_fire_type","int_value":0}],"present_at_all_locations":true,"category_data":{"name":"Candy"}},{"type":"CATEGORY","id":"KFB7DDQYPG532F66SYAYAD4W","updated_at":"2017-06-13T19:45:27.653Z","version":1497383127653,"is_deleted":false,"present_at_all_locations":true,"category_data":{"name":"Sandwiches"}},{"type":"CATEGORY","id":"SJVUDRCAMQBSRM7FAEBQATBS","updated_at":"2017-06-13T19:45:35.181Z","version":1497383135181,"is_deleted":false,"present_at_all_locations":true,"category_data":{"name":"Specials"}}]}
~END~
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 74.122.190.85...
* Connected to connect.squareup.com (74.122.190.85) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Square, Inc.; CN=*.squareup.com
*    start date: 2016-12-07 00:44:04 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-12-16 01:14:02 GMT
*    subjectAltName: connect.squareup.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /v2/catalog/list?types=CATEGORY HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Square-Connect-PHP/2.2.1
Host: connect.squareup.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer sq0atp-WrF2m45lEzQVzCqAxSA_oA

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 02:29:24 GMT
< Keep-Alive: timeout=60
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631152000
< content-length: 687
< 
* Connection #0 to host connect.squareup.com left intact
```

**EDIT - Solution:** Need to change the object property of $catelogObject to an array not an object as the square connect api documentation instructs

```
foreach ($push_array as $key => $cat_name) {
    $category = $this->products_lib->get_category($cat_name);
    $idempotency_key = uniqid('',true);
    $push_obj = [];
    $push_obj['type'] = 'CATEGORY';
    $push_obj['id'] = '#' . trim($category->name);
    $push_obj['category_data'] = ['name'=>trim($category->name)];
    $push_obj['present_at_all_locations'] = true;
    $catelogObject = ["idempotency_key" => $idempotency_key, 'object' => $push_obj];
    print_r($catelogObject);
    $response = $square_connect->upsert_category($catelogObject);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about which function failed, was it `upserCatalogObject` or building the object that failed? The following gist worked for me without an error: https://gist.github.com/tristansokol/91e0085d7cb9aae762ef1b64bb804a85

Comment: It is during UpsertCatalogObject($category_object) that the error happens. I included the category_object to show what I am passing to UpsertCatalogObject

Comment: Can you set your local library version's `debug` to true and share the output? https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Configuration.php#L104

Comment: Debug output is in the OP, as edit

Comment: I noticed that @tristansokol passed the object property of $catelogObject as an array. When I changed to use an array, all worked properly. Answer is in the OP

Comment: ahh, what is confusing is that the the property is called `object` but it should actually be an associative array. I've submitted an issue against the SDK as a result of this: https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/issues/39